# Angular Make output string available without an emitter

Tags: angular, output

I have two components. Component one is called 'wrapper', component two is called 'list'.

The wrapper component displays the list:

```
<app-list-component></app-list-component>
```

I have a query inside the list component that retrieves an id from the url param from the activated route.

The wrapper component has a few buttons that need that ID.

Is it possible from the list to automatically emit the ID value without the wrapper needing a button click to obtain it?

**List Component**

```
  @Output() URLID = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

My query updates the output with:

```
this.URLID.emit(params.id)
```

**Wrapper component**

```
<app-list-component></app-list-component>
```

I know i need some type of binding here, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that so that it isn't a click event, and instead, the `URLID` is automatically callable within the wrapper component.

Comment: There has to be some custom event even if you don't want a button click. So what type of event would you like

Comment: I think the answer below is fine. I guess what would happen instead of the console log, is that a variable inside the wrapper is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly I think this should fit your needs

wrapper.component.html

```
<app-list-component (URLID)="onUpdateId($event)"></app-list-component>
```

wrapper.component.ts

```
onUpdateId(id: string) {
    //This should fire anytime that the URLID EventEmitter fires
    console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: Damn, that was easy. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. I wasn't sure exactly what the ask was so I went simplest way first.